# React Native - Disable certain navigation in TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

Fairly new and learning React Native.

The project is created with Expo/React Native, I wonder if it is possible to disable Links and Settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/464#issuecomment-310610217) as a working solution. The idea is that by default every screen you put in your stackNavigator is added to this bar, so as you don't want to remove them from your stackNavigator, so you should do another trick. Hope it works for you.